# Optimizing file search

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wicket

I have a large ( around 10 000) database of people. These people can input standard information and upload documents (pdf, .doc & .docx).
When I do a freetext search, it searches through all of the peoples information fields AND their uploaded documents. Searching through ALL of the peoples documents takes so much time wicket throws an "WicketRuntimeException: After 1 minute the Pagemap null is still locked by: Thread ... "

My question is if it's possible to create a search function that can search through up to 10 000 documents without taking extremely long time.

The project is running Java, with Wicket, Hibernate & Spring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing sounds like a direct fit for [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html). Don't reinvent the wheel until you're sure that existing wheels don't meet your needs.

Comment: Apache Lucene is spot on if you are a Java shop.